# App crashing when linking Discord C SDK and not displaying any logs

Tags: c, swift, macos, discord

I am developing a macOS app that uses the Discord SDK (which is written in C). After I import it into another C file that encapsulates all of the logic to initialise it, and then link this C file to my Swift project, the app crashes upon launch, and no errors or crash information is displayed on the output. I have tried importing this same C file into a command line application written in pure C, and it works perfectly.
I would like to know if there's any way to check the error logs outputted from the C code, and where to find it.

Here is the code for the C function I am calling, the crash occurs on DiscordCreate():

```
void initializeDiscord() {
    struct Application app;
    memset(&app, 0, sizeof(app));

    struct IDiscordActivityEvents activities_events;
    memset(&activities_events, 0, sizeof(activities_events));

    struct DiscordCreateParams params;
    DiscordCreateParamsSetDefault(&params);
    params.client_id = CLIENT_ID;
    params.flags = DiscordCreateFlags_Default;
    params.event_data = &app;
    params.activity_events = &activities_events;
    int ver = DISCORD_VERSION;

    DiscordCreate(ver, &params, &app.core);

    app.activities = app.core->get_activity_manager(app.core);
    app.application = app.core->get_application_manager(app.core);
    app.activity_manager = app.core->get_activity_manager(app.core);

    struct DiscordActivity activity;
    memset(&activity, 0, sizeof(activity));
    strcpy(activity.details, "Test");
    strcpy(activity.state, "Test");
    strcpy(activity.assets.large_text, "test");
    strcpy(activity.assets.large_image, "test");
    activity.timestamps.end = (unsigned)time(NULL) + 120;

    app.activity_manager->update_activity(app.activity_manager, &activity, callbackData, callback);

    for (;;) {
        app.core->run_callbacks(app.core);
        usleep(16 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strap it into your debugger and find out why.

Comment: I have tried to debug it, but when it gets to the line that is causing the crash, it simply crashes without outputting any error details. I have edited the question to provide the code for my C function.

Comment: Read up on how to use the XCode debugger tool. You need to add breakpoints to see what is happening and when. Of course there is debug output when it crashes, at the very least you will see the fatal error and its output. If you are not using XCode you should be :)

Comment: I am using the Xcode debugger and I have a breakpoint attached to the line before the error. The problem is that when I step into the function that is causing the crash, it crashes without outputting anything. All of the output I get from my app is "Metal API Validation Enabled", which doesn't seem to be related to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that disabling app sandbox solved the problem. This is probably an issue with the Discord SDK trying to do something that the sandbox doesn't allow.
Still bummed that Xcode showed no warnings, errors or any output at all to indicate that was the issue, but at least it's working now.

Comment: hi i have similar problem, if i remove     DiscordCreate(ver, &params, &app.core); and all lines after program works but if i enable the function again it does not do anything at ,all empty output. what is this sandbox? how to stop it i am using vscode